# CsQuery replace tags

Tags: c#, html, csquery

I using CsQuery in order to parse HTML documents. What I'm trying to do is to replace all the "br" HTML tags with "." character.

Assuming that this is my input HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Hello
        <br>
        World
    </body>
</html>
```

The requested output will be:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Hello
        .
        World
    </body>
</html>
```

Pseudo code:

```
CQ dom = CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://my.url");
dom.ReplaceTag("<br>", ".");
```

Is this possible?

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty easy, just replace the `<br>` elements by setting their `OuterHTML`.
The relevant selector is just `"br"`:

```
foreach (var br in dom["br"])
    br.OuterHTML = ".";
```

Call `dom.Render()` to see the result.